# Usage of “de” that is before an adjective

Tags: grammaire, articles, partitif

Why do you have to include *de* before *nombreux*? Is it because the adjective requires a preposition?  What is the grammatical reason for putting *de* before *nombreux*?

> Pour de nombreux Américains, la guerre contre la pauvreté déclarée il y a cinquante ans par le président démocrate Lyndon B. Johnson est un échec.

Comment: I know it's confusing, but since *pour* is the preposition, *de* cannot also be a preposition. Here it's an article.

Comment: I think your question is more about the rule than the historical reasons for the appearance of this article. So I think it's a duplicate of the other question. If it was about historical reasons please rephrase your question and it will be reopen.

Answer (score 4):

"***de***" is not in that sentence a preposition but an article required for "*Américains*" like one would be in:

- "*Pour **les** Américains, ...*"
- "*Pour **des** Américains, ...*"

Note that in the similar

- "*Pour nombre **d**'Américains, ...*"

"***d***" is not an article but an elided preposition "***de***":

- "For a large number **of** Americans"

Comment: This is my first post, and I am blown away by how fast I have received an answer.  Thank you jlliagre.  I'm slightly confused by the articles in your example... using d'Américains and des Américains.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure you'll get more "professional" answers later. Anyway, in the last example "d'" stands for "de" (elision) and I guess is that time a preposition.

Comment: @Kyle:  In *d'* the apostrophe replaces the *e* that has to be dropped in front of the vowel. Same phenomenon when we say *l'enfant* (but *les enfants*) ...

Comment: @Kyle "des Americains" "des" is equivalent of "some" but with "nombre d'Américain"  "d'" is equivalent of "of" (a large number of american people)

Comment: The second statement was quite confusing, you say “similar” but in “*Pour nombre d'Américains*”, *de* is a preposition; only applicability of the elision rule is “similar”. I tried to make it clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Note that the article used is different depending on whether the adjective precedes the noun or follows it:

(1) De nombreux Américains considèrent que ...

(2) Des Américains influents considèrent que ...

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question that is "*why* is this preposition needed".